# Change foreground of a textbox embedded in a CellTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change the foreground color (text color) of a textbox which is a datatemplate of a GridViewColumn.CellTemplate if the listviewitem is selected:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Components}"
                          Style="{StaticResource PrimaryListViewStyle}"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}"
                          Width="150"
                          MinHeight="150"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged]=[Action ActivateAttributesView($this.SelectedItem)]">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource PrimaryGridViewColumnHeaderStyle}">
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Component Name">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                                   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ComponentViewModel}">
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}">
                                            <TextBox.Resources>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="ListViewItem.IsSelected"
                                                                 Value="False">
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                                                    Value="Green" />
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="ListViewItem.IsSelected"
                                                                 Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                                                    Value="Black" />
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </TextBox.Resources>
                                        </TextBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>

                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Here's an image. Unfortunately I#m not allowed to paste the image directly...:

http://de.tinypic.com/r/262s8bb/8

The text in the selected row shall be displayed "black".

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your style has triggers for the TextBox that it is applied to. A TextBox doesn't know if the containing ListViewItem is selected or not, so this won't work.

To get the connection to the containing ListViewItem, you can use a **DataTrigger** instead, let a **RelativeSource** expression travel up the visual tree until it finds the ListViewItem and bind to its IsSelected property:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
            Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Black" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: That did the trick! Oh my gosh! I spent hours on this :( Now I have to read about datatriggers quickly to understand what's going on here! Thx a lot and happy new year!

Comment: Ok, WPF Unleashed 4.5 tells me that a DataTrigger can be used for non DependencyProperties. But IsSelected is an attached dependency property from "Selector". I think the property type is not important here. I need a DataTrigger because I don't have to name the property as with a Trigger? Is that correct?

Comment: **DataTrigger** works with any property that supports change notification, be it a DependencyProperty or a [CLR property of an object implementing INotifiyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx). **Trigger** only works with DependencyProperties and, more importantly, only with properties of the current object. If you put a trigger in a style for a Button, it will work for properties of this button. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a DataTrigger

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" 
        Value="True">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semilight"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Issue: The data context of the TextBox will be the ComponentViewModel. You don't know if that has an IsSelected property.

Comment: Come on down vote.  What was the problem?  OK without a ComponentViewModel is would not work but is that worthy of a -1?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think it's plain wrong. 1.) The DataTrigger binds to the DataContext by default, and you can't assume there is an IsSelected property. 2.) "The text in the selected row shall be displayed black." You formatted it different. I don't see how that helps a new user.

Comment: @Frank DataTrigger is a step forward.  OP already had the setter property.  Cool but but I don't -1 a step in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1. TextBox listen Foreground changed from ListViewItem

   ```
          <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=Foreground}" />
           </Style>
   ```
2. ListViewItem changed Foreground when IsSelected property changed

   ```
          <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                   </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
   ```